# mySQL Multiple SELECT: 1 complicated 1 simple

Tags: mysql

I want to put two queries together; one from my `posts` table and one from my `store_products` table and display the result on the same page.

so I want to take this...

```
SELECT 
      p.id AS pid 
    , p.uid
    , p.title
    , p.created_at
    , u.id AS uid
    , u.username
    , u.avatar 
    , f.following 
    , l.uid AS liked
    , u2.username AS source_username
    , u2.avatar AS source_avatar
    , u2.created_at AS source_created_at
FROM posts p 
LEFT JOIN users u ON p.uid=u.id 
LEFT JOIN posts_likes l ON l.pid=p.id 
LEFT JOIN follow f ON u.id = f.following 
LEFT JOIN posts p2 ON p.source_hash = p2.hash 
LEFT JOIN users u2 ON u2.id = p2.uid 
WHERE (f.user=2 OR p.uid=2) 
GROUP BY p.id ORDER BY p.id DESC
```

and put it with something like this...

```
SELECT name, price FROM store_products WHERE uid=2
```

I've tried multiple `SELECT` statements, `UNION`, where I'd make up the difference in cols by using `NULL`, I've tried `LEFT`, `RIGHT`, and `INNER` joins, but all those do is add the product info into the other post rows instead of creating separate rows for each product.

The result set I'm looking for is akin to this

```
[0] Post 1
[1] Post 2
[2] Product 1
[3] Post 3
[4] Product 2
```

etc...

Edit: to answer questions. The only relationship between the two tables is the user id, otherwise they are completely separate. I want to provide the visitor a listing of the posts and products, and I'm trying to do it in one query to save server load and also to have them together in the same list instead of separate lists.

Comment: Is there any relationship between the posts and products? Why is `Product 1` after `Post 2`?

Comment: Your question is not very clear. What is the relation between posts and products? Could you provide some sample data?

Comment: `SELECT ..., sp.name, sp.price... ...LEFT JOIN users u ON p.uid=u.id LEFT JOIN store_products AS sp ON (sp.uid = u.uid)` will do what you ask: add rows for each products, on each of those two extra columns will report name and price of product (or NULL). **How to display this** though, it is not MySQL's bailiwick. You need to add some context on what you use to produce that "web page" of yours, and maybe some more question tags. Very possibly what you actually *should* do is keep those two queries separate, and integrate them differently in your CMS of choice.

Comment: @Barmar and abl see edited OP.

Comment: @Iserni I've tried your suggestion and it's giving me the same result as before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a UNION:

```
SELECT 
      "Post" AS type,
    , p.id AS pid 
    , p.uid
    , p.title
    , p.created_at
    , u.id AS uid
    , u.username
    , u.avatar 
    , f.following 
    , l.uid AS liked
    , u2.username AS source_username
    , u2.avatar AS source_avatar
    , u2.created_at AS source_created_at
    , NULL AS product_name
    , NULL AS price
FROM posts p 
LEFT JOIN users u ON p.uid=u.id 
LEFT JOIN posts_likes l ON l.pid=p.id 
LEFT JOIN follow f ON u.id = f.following 
LEFT JOIN posts p2 ON p.source_hash = p2.hash 
LEFT JOIN users u2 ON u2.id = p2.uid 
WHERE (f.user=2 OR p.uid=2) 
GROUP BY p.id 
ORDER BY p.id DESC

UNION

SELECT 
      "Product" AS type
    , NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL
    , name, price
FROM store_products
WHERE uid = 2
```

The application code can then check the `type` column to determine if it's printing a `Post` or `Product`, and format it appropriately.